# jQuery scroll event css-transform causes flickering in Safari

Tags: jquery, scroll, safari, transform, flicker

I now this is a very common bug/problem and there are many proposals out there which I already tried…
So here is my setup:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300%;
}

#test {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $window = $(window)
$window.scroll(function(){
    var $test = $('#test'),
    offset = $window.scrollTop();
    $test.css({
        'transform': 'translateY('+ Math.round(offset*1.2) + 'px) translateZ(0)'
    })
})
```

I tried several configurations which all “failed” in Safari. Even though this is a really simple test-setup it keeps on flickering/stuttering while scrolling. Any ideas?

I have a project with nested, scroll-animated elements to create a nice, new kind of parallax effect – no problem for Firefox and Chrome…

Thanks in advance!